# ConcurrentModificationException, help me understand something

Tags: java, exception

I am not quite sure why i am getting an exception in this method to begin with and why at this location? (No modification happens there)

```
   Iterator<EventGroup> groupIterator = eventGroups.iterator();
   while (groupIterator.hasNext()) {
        EventGroup eventGroup = groupIterator.next();

        Iterator<ScheduledEvent> eventIterator = eventGroup.getEvents().iterator();
        while (eventIterator.hasNext()) {

            ScheduledEvent event = eventIterator.next();   // <------------- ConcurrentModificationException

            boolean found = ((SomeObject) event).getSomeId() == someId;
            if (found) {
                unschedule++;
                unscheduleEvent(event);
                eventGroup.remove(event);

                if (eventGroup.isEmpty()) {
                    eventGroups.remove(eventGroup);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It seems that the only thing being modified here is `eventGroup`, but i am using an iterator to walk over it.

Please help me understand what's happening here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`eventIterator` is an iterator on `eventGroup` and you call `eventGroup.remove(event);` while iterating. You should use the iterator instead to remove the item:

```
eventIterator.remove();
```

This behaviour is explained in the [javadoc of ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html):

> The iterators returned by this class's iterator and listIterator methods are fail-fast: **if the list is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a ConcurrentModificationException.**

Note: you have the same issue with `eventsGroup` and you should replace `eventGroups.remove(eventGroup);` with `groupIterator.remove();`.

Comment: It is so very helpful to get someone else to take a look at the problem. I was staring it in the face and did not see it. Thank you very much